# width property - flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For below code given `width` as `33.3333333333%`, if I change flex-wrap to nowrap in the code, then how would I calculate width ?

```css
.box{
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.box1{ background: #1abc9c; }
.box2{ background: #3498db; }
.box3{ background: #9b59b6; }
.box4{ background: #34495e; }
.box5{ background: #f1c40f; }
.box6{ background: #e67e22; }
.box7{ background: #e74c3c; }
.box8{ background: #bdc3c7; }
.box9{ background: #2ecc71; }
.box10{ background: #16ae85; }


/* flex property for parent(container) - start */
/* Wrapping flex items */
.container{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid goldenrod;
  height:100vh;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /* default value. */
  /*flex-wrap: nowrap; */
}
/* flex property for parent(container) - end */

.box{
  width: 33.3333333333%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class = "container">
      <div class = "box box1">1</div>
      <div class = "box box2">2</div>
      <div class = "box box3">3</div>
      <div class = "box box4">4</div>
      <div class = "box box5">5</div>
      <div class = "box box6">6</div>
      <div class = "box box7">7</div>
      <div class = "box box8">8</div>
      <div class = "box box9">9</div>
      <div class = "box box10">10</div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want...? I don't get it. Please provide any screenshot.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @ankitapatel ok let me rephrase.  if I change `flex-wrap` to `nowrap` in the above code,  then how would you calculcate `width` of each flex item?

Comment: With `nowrap`, first will the sum of the content (numbers) be withdrawn, then each item will shrink equally until they hit each contents minimum.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? ... if to simply understand how Flexbox work, check here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @TemaniAfif You mean,`flex-wrap: wrap` avoids the overflow, so it decides that 3 elements fix per row and wrap for next row. What about `flex-wrap: nowrap`? i do not see overflow, because `33.333333%` is being taken differently

Comment: @LGSon Since years, i follow the same link, but still unclear, when it comes to `flex-wrap: nowrap`. all flex items will be on one line? Breaking the purpose of width.

Comment: A flex item will shrink to fit equal (`flex-shrink` defaults to `1`), and in this case, they will be the same width until the 10th items content is reached, then that one will be wider

Comment: Yes, all items in one line, which its the sole purpose of _nowrap_, and is not breaking the purpose of width, it does what it is told, _nowrap_ ... similar to using `white-space: nowrap` for inline elements

Comment: But why do you want to give `flex-wrap: nowrap;` ?

Comment: @LGSon yes on *nowrap*,it does not wrap. Correct. But, does `width: 33.3%` get satisfied for each flex item?

Comment: @ankitapatel I give *nowrap*, when I want all flex items in one row.

Comment: Yes, they will shrink to fit equal (`flex-shrink` defaults to 1), until an items content stop it...i.e. the 10th will stop shrink first, and this because `min-width` is set to `auto` ... setting it to `0` or add `overflow: hidden` will override that and make them equal no matter content

Comment: @overexchange If you want to give `nowrap`  then items automatically adjust in one row with equal width.

Comment: @ankitapatel No they don't, as it depends on content/parent width as well ... see my previous comment

Comment: @LGSon yes you are right.

Comment: @ankitapatel If i make `font-size:400px`, then, i get horizontal scroll bar, flex items do not get wrapped. you are deviating from question, let me continue with LGSon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this case, and as all flex items share the same width, they will shrink equally until their content stops them.

They do shrink equal as `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`.

They stop at their content width as `min-width` defaults to `auto`, which prevent an item to be smaller than its content.

That can be overridden by either set `min-width` to `0`, or `overflow: hidden` on the flex items

Stack snippet

```css
.box{
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.box1{ background: #1abc9c; }
.box2{ background: #3498db; }
.box3{ background: #9b59b6; }
.box4{ background: #34495e; }
.box5{ background: #f1c40f; }
.box6{ background: #e67e22; }
.box7{ background: #e74c3c; }
.box8{ background: #bdc3c7; }
.box9{ background: #2ecc71; }
.box10{ background: #16ae85; }


/* flex property for parent(container) - start */
/* Wrapping flex items */
.container{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid goldenrod;
    height:100vh;
    flex-wrap:wrap; /* default value. */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

}
/* flex property for parent(container) - end */

.box{
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is just trying to fit all flex-items to actual flex container width, to avoid scrolling left to right. I made `font-size: 400px` to experiment this

Comment: @overexchange No, `overflow: hidden` allows an item to be smaller than its content, which it by default is not, and Yes, as it prevents `flex-shrink` to shrink an item to fit its container.

Comment: item smaller to an **extent** that all the flex items fit in given container width? Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, that is correct as their actual width is initially wider (10 times 33%), so in your case they will always be 10% each (1 of 10) of their parent

Comment: What is `flex-shrink` value in *wrap* case? Bit confusing for me to also consider thinking about `flex-shrink` in my case. Did not expect that you would also consider `flex-shrink` property in my case

Comment: @overexchange `flex-shrink` has a default of `1`, allow an item to shrink, no matter _wrap/nowrap_, though when _wrap_ it will have no effect as the items will simply wrap...so when flex items are bigger to fit parent, _flex-shrink_ will play a role.

Comment: Usage of `overflow:hidden` property always make me feel novice in css. Because in block layouts, *hidden* allows content respecting width and height of the box.

Comment: @overexchange Agree :)